# Sessions unregistering on IE10 (related to register_globals?)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, internet-explorer-10, whm

I have a really weird issue here:
I have a website with a member login form. When you log in, it creates sessions and cookies. The code uses the register_globals parameter, so the session are registered with `session_register()`.

It has always worked well, as far as I know. But in IE10, when I log in, the session is created, it redirects to the member interface, and when checking for the session, it's not there anymore and it goes back to the login form. Sometime I have access to the member interface, but as soon as I change the page, I lose the registered session and go back to the login form.

The problem must be the IE10 configuration, because it works on some computers on IE10, but some others have this problem. But even with all security removed, it still doesn't work.

Do you know from where this might come from?
Thanks a lot.

PS: Just so you know, I inherited this website, I don't use register_globals. Don't throw rocks at me please !

Comment: Does it work in older versions of IE? See if you can capture the requests, with Wireshark if you have to, and check what PHPSESSID is being sent.

Comment: Check whether the cookie is being sent by the client. If not, go read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/17/simple-introduction-to-p3p-cookie-blocking-frame.aspx